# Calling printf, snprintf, f_printf, ect using variables for printf arguments

Tags: c, variables, arguments, printf

Correcting typos:

In c, I'd like to use printf (and its cousins) thusly:

```
    snprintf(cFormatSpecifier,10,"%s","%2.5f");
    float nData=1.234;
    int *pnData=&nData;
    printf(cFormatSpecifier,*pnData);
```

But this fails to produce any output.

It would be handy if this were possible, so the format specifiers and references to data to be printed were in a set of variables.

---

I am encouraged to "Keep it simple", yet can't seem to stop my imagination from wandering off.

My code is complex with a struct instantiated to an array.

```
{
    uint16_t nItem;
    char cColumnHeader[20];
    char  *ptrcPrintfFormat;
    uint8_t nDataLen;
    int *ptrToData;

} oKneeTestReportData;

// loaded with (one of 17 array elements):
    snprintf(aKneeTestReportData[i].cColumnHeader,20,"%s","Timestamp");
    aKneeTestReportData[i].ptrcPrintfFormat="%i\0";
    aKneeTestReportData[i].nDataLen=0;  // if string, this is set
    aKneeTestReportData[i].ptrToData=(int*)&oMasterTime.timestamp;

// where oMasterTime.timestamp is one of many variables that change within a processing loop.  In this same loop, I f_printf() a data column for a report:

f_printf(&oSystemInfo.fUtilityFile,aKneeTestReportData[i].ptrcPrintfFormat,*aKneeTestReportData[i].ptrToData);

// where [i] in this instance refers to the aKneeTestReportData element and *aKneeTestReportData[i].ptrToData dereferences.
```

As I have aKneeTestReportData[i].ptrToData holding the address of the data variable, whatever the contents of the variable be, it should f_printf() just fine.  But instead I get nothing.

As for this great suggestion:

```
float *pnData=&nData;
printf(cFormatSpecifier,*pnData);
```

There are ints, floats and strings in the referenced data variable.  I want one pointer in my structure to point to the data variable, and this pointer has to be "generic".  Maybe this is impossible?

There's something simply stupid in what I'm doing here, but can't see it (forest and trees).  About to abandon this method and simply hard-code my report, but stubborn as I am...

---

OK.  This works.

```
    oKneeTestReportData aKneeTestReportData[2]; 
    // load it
    int ij=0;
    float nfData=123.456;
    snprintf(aKneeTestReportData[ij].cColumnHeader,20,"%s","Timestamp");
    aKneeTestReportData[ij].ptrcPrintfFormat="%i\0";
    aKneeTestReportData[ij].ptrToData=(int*)&oMasterTime.timestamp;

    ++ij;
    snprintf(aKneeTestReportData[ij].cColumnHeader,20,"%s","Float Data");
    aKneeTestReportData[ij].ptrcPrintfFormat="%2.5f\0";
    aKneeTestReportData[ij].ptrToData=(int*)&nfData;

    ij=0;
    char cPrintOut[80];
    while(true)
    {

        printf("Printing first variable [%i] using format[%s] \n\r",oMasterTime.timestamp,aKneeTestReportData[0].ptrcPrintfFormat);

        // compiler warns that format string is not a string literal.. potentially unsecure
        printf(aKneeTestReportData[0].ptrcPrintfFormat,*aKneeTestReportData[0].ptrToData);

        printf("\n\r");

        // my printf doesn't do floats
        snprintf(cPrintOut,80,"Printing second variable [%2.5f] using format[%s] \n\r",nfData,aKneeTestReportData[1].ptrcPrintfFormat);
        printf(cPrintOut);

        // compiler warns that format string is not a string literal.. potentially unsecure
        snprintf(cPrintOut,80,aKneeTestReportData[1].ptrcPrintfFormat,*aKneeTestReportData[0].ptrToData);
        printf(cPrintOut);

        printf("\n\r");

        ++ij;
        if (ij>5)
            break;

        delay_s(1);
        UpdateClockTime();  // updates timestamp
        nfData=nfData+ij;
    }
```

Output:

```
Printing first variable [1560499764] using format[%i]
1560499764
Printing second variable [123.45600] using format[ f]
123.45600
Printing first variable [1560499806] using format[%i]
1560499806 // debug pause caused time lapse
Printing second variable [124.45600] using format[ f]
124.45600
```

I'm guessing that the printf of my format specifier failed as it was interpreted as a format specifier in the text!

So back to my even more complex code to find out where I broke it.

Thanks to everyone for helpful suggestions, critique, and ideas!

Comment: Turn on more compiler warnings, or use a better compiler

Comment: After correcting what I can only call typos, it works. https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS/@vnJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2HHxZWZV6KQm5iZp6ChqVDNpQAEyRmJRQrJbvlFuYklwQWpyZlpmalF0YYGsdb/QdLFeQVFQE1pGuhKdAwNdJRUi5WAhJGeaZqSpjXYuLSc/MQShTyXxJJEW0M9I2MTZGGtAoiEGpiCyOAyHqpW0/p/7f9/yWk5ienF/3XDUytKihKBdGJODgA

Comment: "Typo" 1: `float *pnData=nData;` should not compile. You cannot assign a value of type `float` to a variable of type `float *`. "Typo" 2: `printf(cFormatSpecifier,&pnData);` passes a pointer to pointer to `float` to a format specifier expecting a `double`. This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @jxh : I think it is a misunderstanding rather then a typo - it would be useful if you were to post that code in an answer rather then a link to elsewhere.

Comment: @Clifford: If I assume he had code that actually compiled, I think it is safer to assume the post has typos.

Comment: @jxh : Fair point;  depends what _"fails to produce any output"_ means - certainly there is no output from compilation!

Comment: Actually `snprintf(cFormatSpecifier,10,"%s","%2.5f")` is a convoluted way to say `strcpy(cFormatSpecifier, "%2.5f")`.

Answer (score 1):

After your `snprintf`, variable `cFormatSpecifier` should contain `"%2.5f"`.
But in your `printf` statement you are then passing a pointer to a pointer to a float where a `"%2.5f"`, i.e. a float, is expected.
Write ...

```
printf(cFormatSpecifier,nData);
```

or

```
printf(cFormatSpecifier,*pnData);
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: I should have explained this distinction: I set up a pointer to the source data (nData), as nData is but one of several variables holding data.  As such, printf needs to get its data argument from the stored pointer.  This is why I'm de-referencing the pointer.  As such, shouldn't the float be passed into printf?

Comment: See edited answer; you probably wrote `&pnData` (taking the address of the pointer)  instead of `*pnData` (taking the value to which `pnData` points to).

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want this:

```
strcpy(cFormatSpecifier, "%2.5f"). 
printf(cFormatSpecifier, nData);
```

or

```
const char *cFormatSpecifier;
...
cFormatSpecifier = "%2.5f"; 
printf(cFormatSpecifier, nData);     
...
printf(cFormatSpecifier, otherData);     
...
cFormatSpecifier = "%5.2f"; 
printf(cFormatSpecifier, nData);     
...
```

Keep it simple.